# How many fields can exist in a document?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to know if it is possible to have millions of fields in my ***world*** document? Is there a limit?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How many fields can exist in a document?

As many as you add. The constraint isn't about the number of fileds is about size of the document. So there are some limits when it comes to how much data you can put into a document. According to the official documentation regarding [usage and limits](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas):

> Maximum size for a document: 1 MiB (1,048,576 bytes)

As you can see, you are limited to 1 MiB total of data in a single document. In this 1Mib you can add as many fieds as you want.

> I want to know if it is possible to have millions of fields in my ***world*** document?

I'm afraid that in a single document you cannot add millions of fields. For that you should use separate documents.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at the [documented limits](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas) for Cloud Firestore.  It doesn't say anything about the number of fields in a document, but it does talk about the maximum total size of a document (1MB) and the the max number of index entries for a document (40,000).  So, I think you will be impacted by either of those limits instead of the raw number of fields.  It sounds like if you add more than 40,000 fields to a document, you won't be able to query using those fields after 40,000.